# "it does nothing" vs "it doesn't do anything"

Tags: difference, phrase-usage, negation

My colleague and I are software developers and we were reviewing a particular block of code that has been there for ages and when we shared it with the lead these two phrase were used and it caught my attention. I wondered if they meant the same thing:

> "it does nothing" vs "it doesn't do anything"

I was discussing this with my colleague at work and he argued that the first one is the correct one.  But I felt that there's no difference.

Comment: Both means the same....there is no difference between the two...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both mean the same but for clarity I'd use "it does nothing" because it is simpler

Answer (score 0):

In the general use they would mean the same thing.

If you wanted to get real pedantic, you could say like, a commented out line doesn't do anything, since the program never reads it at all, while the line "if(false)" does nothing, because while the computer executes the line, the state of the program didn't change. It still does something, even if that something was nothing. (Assuming the compiler isn't smart enough to automatically remove the line)